# What do these variables mean in the Kohana framework?

Tags: php, kohana

In general, PHP server variables start with `$_` like `$_REQUEST`,`$_GET` etc but in kohana framework some variables are like `kohana::$_paths`,`Kohana::$_modules` etc.

Are these server variables?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How PHP server variables starts with "$_",similarly Kohana framework defined these variables.

Answer (score 3):

These variables have an underscore to indicate that they are **private members** (or in this case protected) of the core kohana class. You will find this coding standard throughout the whole framework.